# No output when running spark NetworkWordCount example

Tags: scala, apache-spark, docker

I am a Beginner of spark, and I am trying to use docker to run spark example [NetworkWordCount](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Forg%2Fapache%2Fspark%2Fexamples%2Fstreaming%2FNetworkWordCount.scala). But no output when I run the example:

start a new terminal by `docker exec -it container_id bash`,

```
root@sandbox:/usr/local/spark# nc -lk 9999
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
a ba c d e f g
```

then start another terminal:

```
root@sandbox:/usr/local/spark# bin/run-example streaming.NetworkWordCount localhost 9999
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/05/12 02:55:57 INFO StreamingExamples: Setting log level to [WARN] for streaming example. To override add a custom log4j.properties to the classpath.
16/05/12 02:55:58 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
...
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Could you verify with no that what you send indeed reaches local host 9999?

Answer (score 0):

Executing using below command worked for me.

```
[root@quickstart spark]# ./bin/run-example streaming.NetworkWordCount localhost 9999 --master "local[2]"
```